# Django: Launch a server-side computation and dynamically update the client

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am creating a web application with Django (back end) and JavaScript (front end).

The main scenario is the following: a client asks the server to **train a neural network** (which can take quite a lot: seconds or even minutes, sometimes). Immediately after sending the request, the client shows to the user how the training session is going; it does so by retrieving and displaying the **training error**, which is actually just a number.

For training the network I made this function, which I implemented as a **generator**:

```
def train(network, trainset):
    # [setup variables...]
    while (current_error > target_error):
        # [continue to train the network...]
        # [update current_error...]
        yield current_error
```

On the front end (a simple HTML page) I have a JS script for retrieving data dynamically from a Django view. My Django view goes something like this:

```
def getError(request):
    # ...
    generator = train(net, dataset)
    return StreamingHttpResponse(generator)
```

At the moment I can retrieve the data with an AJAX call but I always have to wait for the server to train the **whole** neural network before I can see the training errors.

My problem is that I would like the user to view the error updates *while* the server is training the network, not after: that's why I implemented the training function as a generator (and that's why I chose to return a `StreamingHttpResponse`).

What can I do for retrieving the data while the server is computing? Specifically, I would like to update the front end each time the training generator `yield`s a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: use celery for the computation, storing progress in redis, and have your front side js code poll a view that will get progress from a dedicated view.

Solution 2: use a websocket.

Comment: In case of websocket you might want to have a look at [django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as you already use django.

Comment: I am now studying websockets and they seem a very good solution to my problem. Specifically, Django Channels seems great. But I was wondering: is it really impossible to use "vanilla" Django with `StreamingHttpResponse`?

Answer (score 2):

**Initial analysis:**

Let's have a look at the documentation:

1. [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions):

   > The yield expression is used when defining a generator function
2. [`generator`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator):

   > A function which returns a generator iterator. It looks like a normal function except that it contains yield expressions for producing a series of values usable in a for-loop or that can be retrieved one at a time with the next() function.

From the aforementioned it is clear that your code sample works well but not as intended:

The `train()` function `yields` a `generator` which gets "transmitted" to your front-end from the `getError` after the whole calculation is done.

---

**Reform the problem based on analysis:**

With the above mentioned, your problem will be to get the calculations of each step of the `train()` process and display them to the front-end.

---

**A skeleton of a solution:**

- Create a global variable (yes I said it) list.
- Refactor `train()` function to use the previous list:

  ```
  train_errors = []

  def train(network, trainset):
      # [setup variables...]
      while (current_error > target_error):
          # [continue to train the network...]
          # [update current_error...]
          train_errors.append(current_error)
  ```
- Assuming that `train()` is located in `views.py` file, refactor the `getError()` to return the `train_errors` list:

  ```
  from django.http import JsonResponse

  def getError(request):
      # ...
      return JsonResponse(train_errors, safe=False)
  ```

  I utilize [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), but feel free to use anything that suites you.
- Make your front-end to repeat the AJAX call every N seconds, by utilizing javascript's [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), and display the differences from the previous state of the data. 
  Example of use:

  ```
  var myIntervalCall = setInterval(myAJAXcall, 500);

  function myAJAXcall{
    // Create your AJAX call in here 
    // And sufficient code to display the changes on the received data.
  }
  ```

  The above code will make `myAJAXcall` to the back-end, every `0.5 sec`

The above will allow you to make an initial approach to your problem and you can/must expand on this (barbaric) solution.

---

**EDIT/Disclaimer** (due to @George and @brunodesthuilliers comments):

**The above, is not a good solution!!** It is only a quick solution to get the author "unstuck" from his current problem and help him move on with his development.
 The "solution" provides the basis for a thought process, considering the problem at hand (the actual problem that the author has at the moment) and therefore provides a minimal and initial approach to a solution.

The aforementioned distiled: **DO NOT TAKE THIS SOLUTION AS CANON!** it is only a "jump start".

Comment: Using a global in this context is garanteed to "kind of" work running on  the dev server and become totally erratic once deployed on a multithreaded or multiprocess production server.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That is why I state that this is only a skeleton of a solution! It needs improvement, but it gets out of scope of this question!

Comment: I share the same fear as Bruno's: my application will receive many calls at one time, so a global variable could become a bottleneck, even if I used some global dictionary for mapping each user to a specific `train_errors` list.

Comment: @George You are correct to fear that may happen! I do not suggest this as an ultimate solution, only as a way to unstuck from your current problem and move forward. I will edit my answer to clarify that point!

Comment: Ok, I undertand. Thanks for that!

Comment: No problem mate :) I have added a warning to make it clear!

Comment: Great :) for now I'm using your solution, but I will probably accept Bruno's answer (as it is more "production-friendly"), after trying websockets.

Comment: Fine by me mate :). Happy that my answer unstuck you!